# Using Spanish words for file/class names in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, console, cakephp-1.3

I have a project with spanish characters, like (ñ,á) and Im using the 'ñ' character in one model.
then I had to change the collation and charset to utf-8.
I changed the default setting my.ini, httpd.conf, and php.ini

in my.ini i have this..

```
 **[mysqld]
 port=3306
 character_set_client='utf8'
 character-set-server='utf8'
 collation-server=utf8_general_ci**
```

the problem is when i try to use the console with cake bake...because i have a model named 'Dueño' with the (ñ) character and doesnt show properly 
     (with strange character like 'Due|-#o') and cant create the application with 'cake bake'

Comment: Are you saying that your model *class* is named Dueños? This seems like a very bad idea.. My advice would be: translate the application output properly, but keep the code in English character set at all times.

Comment: I changed the names of my tables for avoid problems dealing with the charset.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad coding practice to name files and classes in such a manner.
The best solution would be to use English names for files and classes. Furthermore 
Cake would lose it's "convention power" if you use any language except English as the Inflector class which is responsible for managing the naming conventions would not 
do it's job at all because it would not manage to "pluralify/singalify" any of the Spanish (or whatever other language) words you would use for your files/classes.

Check out what [Inflector](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html) does if you're interested in this.

I am not saying that it is not possible but this renders CakePHP's "Convention over configuration" principle useless.